# Square PHP API - Record Data

Tags: api, payment, square, square-connect

I am new at this payment API and understanding of Arrays().... I am using Squares PHP API script expample... I like it, however, when it processes the payment, I want to catch certain data and record to sql (mysqli)... I can't even make the script echo the specific data I want... I am lost... Could someone get me in the right direction?

Here is the form: (index.php)

```
    <?php
require '../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/
# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'sandbox-XXXXXX';
# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}
# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}
\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
$locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();
try {
  $locations = $locations_api->listLocations();
  #We look for a location that can process payments
  $location = current(array_filter($locations->getLocations(), function($location) {
    $capabilities = $location->getCapabilities();
    return is_array($capabilities) &&
      in_array('CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING', $capabilities);
  }));
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
  exit(1);
}
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);
# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transactions_api->charge($location->getId(), $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "Card has been Approved!";
  echo $result['amount'][0];
  echo $result['transaction_id'][1];
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
```

And here is the processor (process-card.php)

```
<?php
require '../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
# Replace these values. You probably want to start with your Sandbox credentials
# to start: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox/
# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = 'sandbox-XXXXXX';
# Helps ensure this code has been reached via form submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}
# Fail if the card form didn't send a value for `nonce` to the server
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
if (is_null($nonce)) {
  echo "Invalid card data";
  http_response_code(422);
  return;
}
\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
$locations_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\LocationsApi();
try {
  $locations = $locations_api->listLocations();
  #We look for a location that can process payments
  $location = current(array_filter($locations->getLocations(), function($location) {
    $capabilities = $location->getCapabilities();
    return is_array($capabilities) &&
      in_array('CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING', $capabilities);
  }));
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
  exit(1);
}
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$request_body = array (
  "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
  # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
  "amount_money" => array (
    "amount" => 100,
    "currency" => "USD"
  ),
  # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
  # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
  # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
  # the buyer.
  "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);
# The SDK throws an exception if a Connect endpoint responds with anything besides
# a 200-level HTTP code. This block catches any exceptions that occur from the request.
try {
  $result = $transactions_api->charge($location->getId(), $request_body);
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "Card has been Approved!";
  echo $result['amount'][0];
  echo $result['transaction_id'][1];
  echo "</pre>";
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
  echo "Caught exception!<br/>";
  print_r("<strong>Response body:</strong><br/>");
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseBody()); echo "</pre>";
  echo "<br/><strong>Response headers:</strong><br/>";
  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($e->getResponseHeaders()); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Example: I want to write the transaction data to the "transactions" table with the member's ID number and transaction number and if it was approved or declined.

Thank you!!!! I hope what I am attempting to do isn't too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `var_dump()` instead of echo if you are having problems displaying things with `echo`, and you might learn some more info about what object you are using.

Instead of `$result['amount'][0]` try something like `$result->getTransaction()->   getTenders()[0]->getAmountMoney()->getAmount()` You aren't seeing anything echo'd because you are trying to print things that don't exist.

Don't forget to check out the documentation as well:https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/ChargeResponse.md

Answer (score 0):

We need to check the class member variable, if it is a object of any class or just like normal datatype as int, string.

If it is object of other related class, we need to go in this way.

```
//Last four digits of card
$card_last4 = ($result->getTransaction()->getTenders()[0]->getCardDetails()->getCard()->getLast4());

//Card Brand Like, VISA,AMEX
$card_brand = ($result->getTransaction()->getTenders()[0]->getCardDetails()->getCard()->getCardBrand());
```

These classes and functions can be found under Models at below path.
**\vendor\square\connect\test\Model**

Hope this will help!!